# Unable to install java8 using PPA repository on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, java-8, ubuntu-16.04, apt-get

Getting below errors from 17-jan 2018:

```
--2018-01-18 09:59:52--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 104.94.43.14
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.94.43.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily

--2018-01-18 09:59:52--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516269712_4add28cbea8b722e5136a80b8de32670
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|104.94.43.14|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
```

Commands we are executing to install java8 on Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

getting similar error for java7 and java9 as well.

Please take a look into this issue and let me know if any workaround

Comment: I can confirm the `404`, experienced the same problem today. Maybe just wait 1 or 2 days, until the webmaster at Oracle has scanned the log files for `404` more closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, Oracle changed the policy to remove outdated updates pretty quickly these days (in this case: 8u151/8u152). Sadly, the [`ppa:webupd8team/java`](http://www.webupd8.org/p/ubuntu-ppas-by-webupd8.html)-maintainers did not yet publish an updated version of their packages which matches the latest JDK release (8u161). They should, however, do this to change the download URLs for the respective JDK archives (as published by Oracle).

In case you need an urgent update and/or as a "temporary" workaround you can get the latest version of Oracle JDK via the following steps:

1. Create a tmp directory in your user home and download the current JDK update 161 via `wget`.

   ```
   mkdir ~/tmp
   cd tmp
   wget --continue --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=a" 'http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/jdk-8u161-linux-x64.tar.gz'
   ```
2. Unpack it in the `tmp`directory

   ```
   tar -xf jdk-8u161-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ```
3. Clear out the old installation and move the contents extracted into `jdk1.8...` to the system-wide JDK installation directory:

   ```
   sudo rm -R /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle 
   sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
   sudo mv jdk1.8.0_161/* /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
   sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
   ```
4. Run:

   ```
   sudo /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
   ```
5. Check the current java version by running:

   ```
   java -version
   ```

Note well: The URL used in step 1 points to a `x64` JDK assuming a non-32bit system environment. You can easily change it by inspecting the [official download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) by Oracle.

Hope it helps (as a workaround).

Comment: In the meantime, 8u161 is available via `ppa:webupd8team/java` repository. Still, this solution will work for future versions, most likely 8u171, 8u181 etc.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/jdk-8u161-linux-x64.tar.gz not available Use this https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 1):

There is one more workaround for this problem that I've used previously. For me this was simpler approach:

```
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y oracle-java8-set-default -y || true
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
sudo sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u151|JAVA_VERSION=8u162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u162-b12/0da788060d494f5095bf8624735fa2f1/|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c78200ce409367b296ec39be4427f020e2c585470c4eed01021feada576f027f"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="68ec82d47fd9c2b8eb84225b6db398a72008285fafc98631b1ff8d2229680257"|' oracle-java8-installer.*
sudo sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_151|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_162|' oracle-java8-installer.*
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default -y
```

Initially solution was published here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2374686&page=4&p=13731177#post13731177